# Change a person custom string using ADP's API

Tags: adp-api

I'm trying to change a custom, string field for an ADP worker record:

```
{
    "workers": [
        {
            "associateOID": "{{employeeAOID}}",
            "person": {
                "customFieldGroup": {
                    "stringFields": [
                        {
                            "itemID": "9200623814984_1",
                            "nameCode": {
                                "codeValue": "employeeID",
                                "shortName": "employeeID"
                            },
                            "stringValue": "LOREM"
                        }
                    ]
                }...
```

The [documentation](https://developers.adp.com/build/api-explorer/hcm-offrg-wfn.next.gen/hcm-offrg-wfn.next.gen-hr-workers-person-custom-data-management-v2-workers-person-custom-data-management?operation=POST%2Fevents%2Fhr%2Fv1%2Fworker.person.custom-field.string.change) says that I need to POST to `/events/hr/v1/worker.person.custom-field.string.change` with this body:

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "data": {
        "eventContext": {
          "worker": {
            "associateOID": "{{employeeAOID}}",
            "person": {
              "customFieldGroup": {
                "stringField": {
                  "itemID": "9200623814984_1"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "transform": {
          "worker": {
            "person": {
              "customFieldGroup": {
                "stringField": {
                  "nameCode": {
                    "shortName": "employeeID"
                  },
                  "stringValue": "IPSUM"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Including a `roleCode` header of employee,manager,practitioner,administrator, or supervisor.

Unfortunately, the response returns an exception:

> Label not found, missing following key: Exception in the requestorg.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: com.adp.wfn.chr.model.setup.CustomField@3c1, for class: com.adp.wfn.chr.model.setup.CustomField

What am I missing?